# Changing password of postgresql9 node through Jelastic API not works

Tags: jelastic

I'm trying to change postgres9 DB password.
After upgrading Jelastic platform up to 2.5.3 on my hosting provider, I can't change webadmon database password to user defined through Jelastic API. 
I using com.jelastic.api.environment.Environment.resetNodePassword(String, String, String, String) method of jelastic-public-j2se 2.2 library.
All the time when I calling it, autogenerated password sends me on email, but not password defined by me.
It worked on 1.9 platform version before upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have noticed that the difference in the version numeration is considerable, which indicates that there was done a lot of improvements, features and were successfully fixed detected issues.

I have checked [Release Notes](http://docs.jelastic.com/release-notes-22#b) section which is states that API feature was submitted in 2.2 Jelastic version. 
Referring to API docs currently this can be done by **ResetNodePasswordById** method.

[image: api]